# Configure a project to preserve case on OSX

Tags: macos, git

I'm working on projects where some of the developers are using case-insensitive OSX filesystems.  I was wondering if there's a configuration file+directive I can put in git projects to override/set system-level git configs for case sensitivity.  Specifically to "turn it on" so that when the case of a path changes, git will track it as a change?

Comment: Not sure there is.  I recently had a surprise when publishing a repo to github, only to find duplicated paths in the tree.  I had to create a case-insensitive `.dmg` in order to fix it.  I think once it's fixed, it should stay fixed?

Comment: There's a per-user or global git setting you can toggle to enable case sensitivity on case-insensitive filesystems.  I just was wondering if it could be applied via something like a `.gitattributes` or some other bundled settings file.